# Theme CSS selection element conflict in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, selection

I have edited my custom CSS to include `::selection{color: white; background: #2f3f58;}` or multiple similar variations including copy/pasting and then editing code from W3Schools, W3C, stack overflow, and other sites. The code does nothing. I am using the http://alxmedia.se/themes/hueman/ Hueman theme and it has almost the exact same code that seemed to be working. So i copied this code into my custom CSS and edited it and that did not work either. Finally i disabled the theme CSS pertaining to selections. No matter what I do my selection color is the same red set in the theme options menu as a primary color. The hex for that red is not in the theme CSS however except in the commented out selection element that I am replacing. Is there any way to override the highlight color using CSS that is not the `::slection:` element or am I using the element wrong?

the code is now

```
::selection {
    color: white !important; 
    background-color: #2f3f58 !important;
}
```

much thanks to @citizenen and is wonderful suggestion

Comment: You should also add this to your CSS
 `::-moz-selection{color: white; background: #2f3f58;}`

Comment: thanks I will make sure I have the `-moz-selection` element but this should not affect my view of the website in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right element for selection color. You can use the "!important" property to raise the specificity and force the style over others. Also use "background-color" instead of just "background". Try changing it to this:

```
::selection {

color: white !important; 
background-color: #2f3f58 !important;

}
```

More on !important here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

You are missing a closing brace in your CSS file (custom.css) that's preventing styles after that point from applying correctly. In the future, copy your code into a tool like Lint (http://csslint.net/) and it will find the errors for you.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks @citizenen I updated the code to your revision but it still highlights red with gray text. I did however forget to mention that the red color appears to be set by the theme settings primary color but i do not want to change that because it would also change the sidebar color. Is there any way too override this setting? (i have updated my original post to include this information)

Comment: Hm that should work unless the theme is ALSO using '!important'. What's the name of the stylesheet that you're editing (.css)?

Comment: custom.css but the commented out code is in style.css and was written by the theme

Comment: custom CSS _should_ automatically override all other stylesheets

Comment: and !important should override any settings regardless of specificity. Unless they're using JS to overwrite it manually.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace on line 72 of custom.css.

Comment: @citizenen: I have not looked at any JS and do not know any of the language. where would this code be and what would it look like?

Comment: @BrendanJackson see my comment about line 72 (missing closing brace). This is preventing parsing on the rest of the file.

Comment: thank you guys so much, sorry for wasting your time I did not pick that up even when i pasted into dreamweaver

Comment: All good my man - another set of eyes is needed sometimes. Can you mark as correct answer? Appreciate it.